# How to set anaconda as default python interpreter in the windows-linux-subsystem?

Tags: anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently installed the UBUNTU 18.04 subsystem and want to set anaconda as my default python interpreter.Anaconda was installed before the subsystem and I would like a way to do so without reinstalling the python distribution.

Comment: `conda init bash` should do the trick.

Comment: can you clarify where I should use this. gives 'command not found ' in the anaconda prompt.

Comment: In the WSL terminal. If you want to set something for WSL, you should be using the WSL terminal...

Comment: Doesn't work there as well, says conda not found

Comment: Where/how did you install conda?

Comment: On Windows before I installed the subsystem

Comment: Then you have to install Anaconda/miniconda within the subsystem

Comment: Yeah, realised that was a viable option  that's why stated this in the question, wanted to know if there was a way by updating the path somehow.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misread your question.